# Java ArrayList contains amount?

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there any way to figure out how many of something an ArrayList contains?
Let's say:

`ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Hi");
list.add("Hi");
list.add("Hi");`

Now I want to be able to figure out how many "Hi"'s are in there.. any easy method or small codeblock to?

Comment: You'll need a compound `for-loop`, `Object#equals` and probably some kind of `Map` to hold the results ;)

Comment: A for-each loop would be four lines. Also, please don't use raw-types with `Collection`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Collections.frequency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29).  So in your example, `Collections.frequency(list, "Hi");`

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new :) - I would also mention the need for the objects to meet the requirements of the `Object#equals` contract ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Standard JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) already provides `Collections.frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)` that does exactly this.